# How to implement facebook post loader in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Here I have attached a video link I need this feature I don't know how it's working in ionic. In this video he was log into the app then the app gets loaded and the card makes load effect(like FB) how it was done? 
Please share the knowledge about what he was done in the video?
how to implement facebook

http://ytcropper.com/cropped/Ba59eb092699f43

Source video link is 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ba4EjF-p7cs

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the solution !!
Its called skeleton loading when server data are not received this skeleton loading will appear and then disappear when the server data received
here is the link for the demo

https://codepen.io/oslego/pen/XdvWmdt

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple html and css code to implement what you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* 
Animated skeleton screen using CSS.

Create shapes using gradients that simulate solids.

Use `:empty` pseudo-class to show skeleton screen background only while container has no content (ex: for the "loading" state). When content is added to the container element, the pseudo-class selector won't match anymore and the skeleton screen will be removed automatically; no need to toggle a separate class on the container.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Animating one layer of the background which is a tilted linear gradient with white in the middle to achieve shine effect.
*/
    .demo:empty {
    margin: auto;
        width: 500px;
        height: 600px; /* change height to see repeat-y behavior */

        background-image:
            radial-gradient( circle 50px at 50px 50px, lightgray 99%, transparent 0 ),
            linear-gradient( 100deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80% ),
            linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
            linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
            linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
            linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 );

        background-repeat: repeat-y;

        background-size:
            100px 200px, /* circle */
            50px 200px, /* highlight */
            150px 200px,
            350px 200px,
            300px 200px,
            250px 200px;

        background-position:
            0 0, /* circle */
            0 0, /* highlight */
            120px 0,
            120px 40px,
            120px 80px,
            120px 120px;

        animation: shine 1s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes shine {
        to {
            background-position:
                0 0,
                100% 0, /* move highlight to right */
                120px 0,
                120px 40px,
                120px 80px,
                120px 120px;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>

<div class="demo"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```